# c++ - #ifdef macro

Tags: c++

I can see

```
#ifdef <token>
code;
#endif
```

to be included, but I can't find it defined in any of the headers it includes. Is there any other mechanism with which the token could be defined?

Comment: You can specify it with /D on cl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, preprocessor directives can be set with the compiler. For example, gcc lets you add directives in the command line, you can specify directives in the project settings in Visual Studio. Also think about `__cplusplus`, or `_LINE_` of `_FILE_`. Those aren't defined anywhere, yet they exist. Also `_DEBUG` or `UNICODE` which are set up by the MSVS environment.

Comment: can you please give some more details? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, there are macros that are implicitly defined by the compiler (for example, `__cplusplus`). Some of these are standard, and some are compiler-specific extensions. See your [compiler manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Predefined-Macros.html#Predefined-Macros) for the full list.

Additionally, most compilers allow defining macros on the command line. The exact mechanism is compiler-dependent, but often takes the form of a `-D` or `/D` command-line option. For example, see the [`gcc` manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options):

> `-D name`
>
> Predefine name as a macro, with definition 1.
>
> `-D name=definition`
>
> The contents of definition are tokenized and processed as if they appeared during translation phase three in a `#define' directive. In particular, the definition will be truncated by embedded newline characters.
>   If you are invoking the preprocessor from a shell or shell-like program you may need to use the shell's quoting syntax to protect characters such as spaces that have a meaning in the shell syntax.
>
> If you wish to define a function-like macro on the command line, write its argument list with surrounding parentheses before the equals sign (if any). Parentheses are meaningful to most shells, so you will need to quote the option. With sh and csh, -D'name(args...)=definition' works.

For Microsoft Visual C++, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8(v=vs.80).aspx

Some compilers provide convenient tools for figuring out where a particular preprocessor macro is defined. See, for example, [How to know (in GCC) when given macro/preprocessor symbol gets declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290952/how-to-know-in-gcc-when-given-macro-preprocessor-symbol-gets-declared)

Answer (score 2):

Most (all?) compilers allow defining values with flags (-D in gcc), also some may be set by the compiler itself.

Comment: A good example: compiling with `-DNDEBUG` (gcc) disables `assert` statements. You typically won't find `NDEBUG` defined in a header file. The intent is to have that defined on the command line (or in a makefile).