# XCode Expected unqualified-id TNT (Template Numerical Toolkit)

Tags: c++, xcode

When compiling the [TNT library](http://math.nist.gov/tnt/) i.e. the Template Numerical Toolkit, XCode raises this error:

```
tnt/tnt_array1d_utils.h:33:9: Expected unqualified-id
```

Affected code snippet:

```
namespace TNT
{


template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &s, const Array1D<T> &A)
{
    int N=A.dim1();   /// <--- this line 33:9

#ifdef TNT_DEBUG
    s << "addr: " << (void *) &A[0] << "\n";
#endif
    s << N << "\n";
    for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
       s << A[j] << "\n";
    }
    s << "\n";

    return s;
}
```

Whole TNT header [here](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/7092814)

Tried to add a semi-colon ";" to the end of each template did not work:

```
namespace TNT
{


template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &s, const Array3D<T> &A)
{
    int M=A.dim1();
    int N=A.dim2();
    int K=A.dim3();

    s << M << " " << N << " " << K << "\n";

    for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            for (int k=0; k<K; k++)
                s << A[i][j][k] << " ";
            s << "\n";
        }
        s << "\n";
    }


    return s;
};
```

I'm using

XCode5
GNU++11
libC++

Tried also
libstdc++

Comment: I found somewhere about adding enclosures and ; issue on C++ templates. I did that but with no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example that causes `error: expected unqualified-id` with Clang (on line 5):

```
#define N 

int main()
{
    int N=3;
}
```

because line 5 is expanded to `int  =3;` (you'll also get an error with e.g. `#define N 10` but with an additional `note: expanded from macro 'N'`).

So I would bet that your code is defining a macro `N` somewhere before including the header tnt_array1d_utils.h (maybe in another header, which is evil), which seems a very bad idea (one-letter macro, and before includes).

(Note: It has nothing to do with a missing semicolon. A semicolon is needed after a class definition (template or "plain") but not after a function definition like here. Also, generally, I would recommend you don't modify headers from external libraries.)

Comment: So you mean that this is a semantic error in the Template Numerical Toolkit itself, right? In that case I cannot modify the library.

http://math.nist.gov/tnt/

Comment: That would be surprising. A quick `grep "define N"` over the header files only gives a `#define NULL 0` (tnt_i_refvec.h, line 33). Likely the "`#define N [something]`" is in another part of your project (I suggest you try a textual search).

Comment: Let's consider that this was a XCode5/armv7 project.

Comment: GitHub search gives nothing. I'm not searching the project for you (moreover I'm not familiar with "XCode5/armv7"), but there's another way the error could occur: no actual `#define N` (or e.g. `#define N 10`) in the code but compiling with option `-DN` (or e.g. `-DN=10`).

Comment: Of course. Thanks. I thinks you were right since I've just found this template< BOOST_MPL_AUX_NTTP_DECL(int, N) > struct int_; and the error on "N", so everything brings to think that a #define N is causing a cascaded error here and somewhere else. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes I agree. Now you need to find where that `N` is defined. (This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11257455 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/290952 (don't stop at the first answer))

Comment: I finally fixed this weird issue searching and finding the #define N in the whole project. Nice thing. It was #define N 10 :D