# How to find, from which include file a C preprocessor definition was taken?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

How can I find the include file, from which a certain preprocessor definition was found by GCC?

In a successfully compiling C file, I have a strange macro which I do not understand. For a start, I want to see the file where it comes from. The include hierarchy is very deep; is there an easy way to find the source of the macro?

A [wider question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290952/how-to-know-in-gcc-when-given-macro-preprocessor-symbol-gets-declared) has been asked, but the answers tell how to find the definition itself, not its source file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

redefine it **before** including anything else, the compiler will complain about a redefinition when it encounters it in your header hierachy:

```
#define MY_PROBLEMATIC_MACRO


#include <the_header.h>

/* code */
```